# I am facing "no such column" error in sqlite3 while updating values of a column

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

function which I defined to update the values of a table

```py
def updateInfo(id, term, val):
    try:
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE students SET {term}={val} WHERE id={id}")
    except Error as err:
        print(err)
```

My Table

```sql
CREATE TABLE students(
    id INTEGER,
    fname TEXT,
    lname TEXT,
    branch TEXT,
    course TEXT,
    emailID TEXT,
    mobileNum TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

while taking input from the user only "mobileNum" entered by user is working and for others like "fname" and other I am getting no such column error

```py
stuId = int(input("Enter students ID: "))
upValue = input("What do you want to update: ")
reValue = input("Update the value: ")
updateInfo(stuId, upValue, reValue)
```

Comment: A few remarks:
1. using a cursor defined outside of the function scope is generally a bad idea. Better to pass that to the function as an argument
2. how is the cursor defined? If the cursor is pointing to a different database, that might explain your issues
3. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. While this might be fine if you're the only one to use this code, entering an id value of `1;DROP TABLE students` will erase your table from the data base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `val` is a string it would be interpreted as a column name, since it is not surrounded with quotes. Throw them in there and you should be OK:

```
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE students SET {term}='{val}' WHERE id={id}")
# Here -------------------------------------^-----^
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . But why is that since val is also a string. This works when I entered the value of val - mobileNum. But it didn't work for others

Comment: @PrabhatKumarSingh column names must start with a character. If the value is numeric, it can't be a column, and is just evaluated as a numeric literal